# Connectable webparts in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010

I'd like to learn how to create connectable web parts. Please provide me links or full examples using SP 2010 OM

The example in MSDN has lots of deprecated classes. I need to know how to use SP 2010 classes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms469765.aspx

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching carefully on MSDN I found a simple example that shows how to connect 2 webparts using SP 2010 OM and not deprecated classes from SP 2007.

Very nice and easy to do.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff597538.aspx